# ubuntu file manager: text input for file names (with autocomplete)

Tags: filemanager, auto-completion

I use the default ubuntu file manager. Sorry, I can't give you exact application name, since I could not find it. The german "about" messages just says "Dateien" (german for "Files").

I don't see a text input for quick location of files

I type with ten fingers and really prefer typing to clicking. Is there a way to locate files with the file manager by typing?

Autocomplete would be nice, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just so you know, the default file manager in Ubuntu is `nautilus`. Here are some options:

1. Opening nautilus and just typing should jump to the matching file.
2. Open the `Go` menu and choose `Enter Location...` or just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.
3. In a terminal (you can open one with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) enter `nautilus /folder/to/open`.

Autocomplete using the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key should work for any of these.

Comment: Thank you very much. Best answer was your first note: "1. Opening nautilus and just typing should jump to the matching file." I just type "/" and now I can locate the file (which path I know) very fast. Thank you.